# Clear content of JS element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jsp

I am using angular function to detect the changes.

Each time I change, the another table is created in my webpage of single page application.

My code :

`$('#dynamictable').append('<table></table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();

table.append("<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>");`

How can I reset the table each time I change my content.

Comment: If you're using AngularJS why aren't you utilising data binding etc rather than changing the DOM elements with jQuery?

Comment: can you tell us what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Thank you guys @Simplicity, Sohaib Majeed, P. Janowski $("#triangletable").empty(); solved the issue temporarily but I will check the data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and do this by calling the [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function on your `$('#dynamictable');`

this would look like this:

```
$('#dynamictable > table').empty();
```

Place this wherever you check if there's been a change and this will result in the table being emptied out.

**EDIT**

Only just now noticed the angularjs tag, you're better off trying to do this through data binding than through this method

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question, using jQuery

```
table.empty()
```

But it is not ideal way of doing things, look up data binding with angualjs.

Answer (score 0):

Just empty the table before append new data
So the code should be

```
$('#dynamictable').append('<table></table>');
var table = $('#dynamictable').children();
$(table).empty();
table.append("<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>");
```